# "You must not forget ..... (turn) off your stove, it's very dangerous."

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, verb-usage

I saw this fill in the blanks question on my practice book and it left me confused

> You must not forget ..... (turn) off your stove, it's very dangerous.

For the book, answer is **to turn**. My answer was **turning**

I couldn't decide am I just being wrong but feeling like I am not, or is there can be two answers?

Comment: forget **to do something**.

Answer (score 2):

The book is right - in the context of **not doing something** because you failed to remember to do it, *forget to* is the right construction to use.

> I forgot to turn off my stove. *(I didn't turn the stove off)*

If you *forget doing* something, it means that you did it, but no longer have a memory of doing so:

> I forgot turning off my stove. *(I turned the stove off, but I forgot that I did it)*